# My server name occur an error while parameterizing it

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I'm kinda new with C# and I'm having this problem.

I'm trying to connect to my database in SQL Server 2008 R2 from VIsual Studio 2015 Community.

My server name is ERIC-LAPTOP\SQLMANAGER, but the "\" occurs an error:

```
string connetionString = null;
string servername = "ERIC-LAPTOP\SQLMANAGER";
string database = "RPG_Ressourses";
SqlConnection connection;
connetionString = "Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
```

Is there a way to make it accept \ as a normal character or is there a way to make it work without changing the name of the server instance?

I put the servername and database into var because it will be part of the parameters eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@`

```
string servername = @"ERIC-LAPTOP\SQLMANAGER";
```

or `\\`

```
string servername = "ERIC-LAPTOP\\SQLMANAGER";
```

Comment: It's seems to make the servername work, but is there anything else im my connection string that may not make it right, still don't connect

Comment: @EricBrochu You will need to find the error in the exception and post a new question if google doesnt answer it.

Comment: @EricBrochu Also you might want to read why the backslash was breaking your code. http://www.csharpteacher.com/2013/11/c-character-escape-sequences.html